# typescript ref error on attribute - vuejs

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, ref

Im using Vue **2.6.14**

I want to display img based on URL stored in ref. The problem is that whenever I want to retrieve value from ref I have to do propName.value. Here when i do `:src=specificImg.value` TS is not complaining but the img dont want to load.
When i do `:src=specificImg` img loads correctly but `:src` is getting highlighted and TS is complaining with error -

**Error:**

```
    Type 'Ref<string> | Ref<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'Ref<string>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

Why is that happening?

**EDIT:** I solved issue adding .toString() -  `<img :src="specificImg.toString()" />`. I guess its not clean solution but TS is not complaining. Anyway still interested why TS was complaining about code without `.toString()`.

**Code:**

```
<template>
   <img :src="specificImg" />
</template>


 export default Vue.extend({
  setup(){
     const { data: specificImg} = useQuery( ["specificImg", id],  () =>
      apiService.fetchSpecificImg(id),
    {
    refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    }
    );
     return { specificImg }
   }

  
 })
```

Comment: show me how you defined the ref

Comment: Don't you need Vue 2.7 to use composition?

Comment: @AousMohammad The ref is `specificImg` that is comming from vue-query as you can see in code.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. I dont know tbh. I use 2.6.14 created with Vue CLI and rest of my code that is not included in the code i provided works  inside setup(). But thats weird as i can also read that composition comes with 2.7.

Comment: What IDE are you using? VS Code? What plugin for Vue support? Volar?

Comment: @DarrylNoakes VSC, Volar

Comment: Have you installed any packages such as `@vue/composition-api`?

Comment: The only packages I installed are - vue 2.6.14 from Vue CLI, vue-router 3.6.5 and @tanstack/vue-query